# Adding HTTPS to Azure VM mapped through CNAME

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-virtual-machine

I intend to buy a wildcard `SSL` certificate for `mydomain.com`. From my `ISP` I map `test.mydomain.com` - using `CNAME` setting - to an Azure VM (not a simple web app) running a webserver (e.g. `blahblah-vm.cloudapp.net`) where I have opened port 80 and 443.

Now, my client connects to `https://test.mydomain.com`. Will there be any issues? Do I need to somehow prepare the VM with the `mydomain.com` SSL certificate or will it just work thanks to the `CNAME` mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your VM have a **static Public IP address**? If yes, you could use **A Records**.  Also, we can use **CNAME** map the Azure VM's  FQDN.

> Now, my client connects to https://test.mydomain.com. Will there be
>   any issues?

Before you connect to https://test.mydomain.com, we should **install** SSL certificate on your PC first.

> Do I need to somehow prepare the VM with the mydomain.com SSL
>   certificate or will it just work thanks to the CNAME mapping?

There is no need to prepare something except install SSL certificate.

Update:

If your VM is windows, and use IIS to deploy your web server, we can use SSL certificate here:
[image]

Comment: Do I need to install the certificate manually on the Azure VM? (And on mydomain.com server.) That's all I need to do?

Comment: You just need install SSL certificate on your local PC to browse the web, and configure the SSL certificate in the web configuration. I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: I installed the certificate on ISP (web hotel) where I have a CNAME pointing at my Azure VM server. Do I need to do anything else? Connecting to the CNAME url just says "Waiting for proxy tunnel" in Chrome...

Comment: @I33Tt, according the error massage, it seems that we should enable internet SSL 3.0 and TSL 1.0, please refer to this link https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-enable-ssl-30

Comment: Yes, thanks. Had to install certificate (including all root certificates) on *both* my web server (ISP) and the CNAME-mapped VM. Also, adding the certificate to "Server Certificates" in IIS solved some problems.